# Get reference to master select row in nested select

Tags: mysql, select

I want my DB to return row under one of two conditions:

1. The row contains specific `value` "val" and is of `type` "sometype"
2. There is other row, that does have the `type` "sometype" and the same `name` as currently checked row.

For this purpose, I made a folowing query:

```
SELECT c.name, c.value, c.type
   FROM `table` AS c
   WHERE
      c.type='sometype' AND c.value='val' 
      OR 
      c.type='othertype' AND 
         0<(SELECT count(*) FROM `table` AS d WHERE d.name=c.name and c.name='sometype')
```

Unfortunately, this will return all rows of '`othertype`'. I only want these, that have friend with same name and type 'sometype'.
I think the problem is, that I don't know how to get the reference to the values in curently checked row (which I believed to be `c.fieldname`). I believed `d.name = c.name` would return all rows that have same name as currently checked row. But the nested select is always `>0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for what you are doing:

```
SELECT c.name, c.type, c.value
FROM test as c
INNER JOIN (SELECT name, type
            FROM test
            WHERE type = "type1"
            AND value = 3) as d
ON c.name = d.name AND c.type = d.type;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63255/1

The inner select gets your #1, where type="sometype" and value="val". Then the outer gets the names, types and values that correspond to the name and type of the inner select, which is your #2.

Comment: Glad to hear, not a problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.name
     , c.value
     , c.type
  FROM table c
 WHERE (c.type = 'sometype' AND c.value = 'val') 
    OR (c.type = 'othertype' AND 0< (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` d WHERE d.name = c.name AND c.name='sometype'));
```

also consider rewriting without the subquery

Comment: Why it says `... d.name = c.name AND c.name='sometype' ...`? I mean what is the association of `c.name` and `'sometype'`here?